# How to add or inc to an array in a update query?

Tags: mongodb

If I have a doc which has an array which contains a items which represents counts for a day, perhaps like :-

```
{
  data : [  {'20141102' : 2 },{'20141103' : 4 } ]
}
```

when I do an update, and I have a string `'20141103'` and then later a `'20141104'` I want to either inc the array entry or add a new array entry.  Is this possible with an update?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's feasible. I tried like this:
(run on mongo shell; both client and server are V2.6.4)

```
function tryAndFine(coll, key, value) {
    var entry = {};
    entry[key] = value;

    var parent = 'data';
    var prefix = parent + '.';

    function incrementOnly() {
        var criteria = {};
        criteria[prefix + key] = {$exists : true};

        var update = {};
        update[prefix + "$." + key] = value;

        var result = coll.update(criteria, {$inc : update});
        // if increment fails, try to add a new one
        if (result.nModified == 0) {
            addNewElement();
        }
    }

    function addNewElement() {
        var criteria = {};
        criteria[prefix + key] = {$exists : false};

        var update = {};
        update[parent] = entry;

        var result = coll.update(criteria, {$push : update}, {upsert : true});
        // if exists, try to increment the count
        if (result.upserted == 0 && result.nModified == 0) {
            incrementOnly();
        }
    }

    // run entry
    incrementOnly();
}

// test
var c = db.c;
c.drop();
tryAndFine(c, '20141103', 1);
tryAndFine(c, '20141103', 1);
tryAndFine(c, '20141104', 1);
tryAndFine(c, '20141105', 1);
tryAndFine(c, '20141104', 1);

// output
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("54577e1a3502852bd4ad2395"),
    "data" : [ {
        "20141103" : 2
    }, {
        "20141104" : 2
    }, {
        "20141105" : 1
    } ]
}
```